# Reverse for 'projeto' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/projeto/$']

Tags: python, django, user-interface, view, foreign-keys

Hail Devs. I have an app that in the index I call some queries with ForeignKey between table fields, using the User as argument. The views work for other tables without ForeignKey.  But when I invoke the CRUD (delete, update, create) functions that request the database, it returns an error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete/13/
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'projeto' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/projeto/$']
Exception Location: C:\webcq\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\webcq\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\webcq',

 'C:\\webcq\\venv',
 'C:\\webcq\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 20 May 2021 21:03:07 +0000
```

url.py project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path


urlpatterns = [


    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('imagem.urls', namespace='home')),
    path('view/<int:pk>/', include('imagem.urls', namespace='view')),
    path('edit/<int:pk>/', include('imagem.urls', namespace='edit')),
    path('update/<int:pk>/', include('imagem.urls', namespace='update')),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', include('imagem.urls', namespace='delete')),


]
```

urls.py app

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'imagem'

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('projeto/', views.projeto, name='projeto'),
    path('form/', views.form, name='form'),
    path('create/', views.create, name='create'),
    path('view/<int:pk>/', views.view, name='view'),
    path('edit/<int:pk>/', views.edit, name='edit'),
    path('update/<int:pk>/', views.update, name='update'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.delete, name='delete'),

]
```

views.py app

> The views work, but do not redirect to the view name and return the above error.

```
def edit(request, pk):
    data = {}
    data['db'] = Projeto.objects.get(pk=pk)
    data['form'] = ProjetoForm(instance=data['db'])
    return render(request, 'imagem/form.html', data)

def update(request, pk):
    data = {}
    data['db'] = Projeto.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = ProjetoForm(request.POST or None, instance=data['db'])
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('imagem:projeto')

def delete(request, pk):
    db = Projeto.objects.get(pk=pk)
    db.delete()
    return redirect('imagem:projeto')
```

form.html

```
          {% for dbs in db %}

            <td>
               <th>{{dbs.id}}</th>
                <td>{{dbs.nome}}</td>
                <td>{{dbs.tipo_img}}</td>
                <td>
                      <a href="/view/{{dbs.id}}/" class="btn btn-dark">Visualizar</a>
                      <a href="/edit/{{dbs.id}}/" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>
                      <a href="/delete/{{dbs.id}}/" class="btn btn-danger btnDel">Deletar</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

models.py app

```
class Projeto(models.Model):
    tipo_img = models.ForeignKey(TipoImg, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    autor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `projeto` is in the `imagem` urls, which is called from `urls.py` with a namespace of 'home', I belive you want to use `return redirect('home:projeto')` in your views (not 'imagem:projeto').

You probably also want to get rid of the 'view', 'edit', 'update', and 'delete' from urls since you have it in imagem as well (or remove it from imagem).

Your first `url.py` should probably be:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('imagem.urls', namespace='home')),
 ]
```

For your future self, you probably want to name your root url file as `urls.py`; other `urls.py` will live in their own app folders usually.

So a file structure like this would result:

```
project_name/project_name/settings.py
project_name/project_name/urls.py
project_name/imagem/urls.py
project_name/imagem/views.py
project_name/imagem/models.py
```

Comment: Thanks DMG. That's really what I needed. I will redo the routes as suggested. Once again, thank you very much!